# SharePoint Workflow Response Code InternalServerError

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, internal-server-error

I'm using SharePoint Designer to create a customer workflow that creates a subsite from a task list. I have this working on 3 other lists in my site collection.

For some reason, on this particular list, my ResponseCode is "`InternalServerError`" and it does NOT create the site. My Response Content is:

```
 {"error":{"code":"-2130575223,
 Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ActivityNotFoundException:
 The activity named 'WorkflowXaml_2c7a21f7_584e_46d2_8b9b_44cc38865cbe'
 from scope
 '\/spo\/b8523793-b582-42ae-98a5-b7ce28a35b18\/8571ed36-3bcd-4bb9-9e34-099d167e4f71\/01db62c3-a69b-4d3d-8d1b-74eda6ed5491'
 was not found. HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId:
 63af53ef-00af-4300-94cb-92f545a8e22e. NodeId: . Scope: . Client
 ActivityId : e11e3990-dd74-cadc-a3af-c0709f8a470c. --->
 System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error"}}}
```

I've spent days researching this and cannot figure out what is wrong. I believe I only have 15 variables so I'm not exceeding the 50 variable max, I've double, triple, quadruple checked my dictionaries and made sure I have the correct type, verified my call is correct, etc.

Servers are my weak point, I just have a difficult time comprehending information related to servers so if you have any advice, no matter how obvious, I'll take it.

I do have Fiddler downloaded and have played around with it, but really have no idea what I'm looking at. I'm willing to do or try anything, just need to be guided a bit.

Thank you in advance for any help anyone has to offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After about a month of researching this, posting on several forums, and just fiddling around with it until I could't bare it any longer, I have come to the conclusion this was a problem specific to me and was not replicated for anyone else out there.

To overcome this obstacle, I created an entirely new Site Collection, not just a new site, but site collection. I had tried a new site within the original site collection but kept receiving the same InternalServerError.

I then recreated my list and workflow, exactly how I had before, and BAM! It worked. Fortunately, this was a situation where it was plausible for me to create a separate site collection. I did not find out the root cause but at least found a way to continue working on my project.